# Postgresql - JSON array operators

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, function, operators

I am trying read a JSON array in Postgresql with the below mentioned JSON content but I couldn't achieve it. I am able to read the JSON objects like "select data ->> 'items' from events". Please let me know an approach where I can read an array, objects inside arrays & inner arrays etc.

**JSON Content:**

```
{"apiVersion":"2.0",
 "data":{
    "updated":"2010-01-07T19:58:42.949Z",
    "totalItems":800,
    "startIndex":1,
    "itemsPerPage":1,
    "items":[
        {"id":"hYB0mn5zh2c",
         "uploaded":"2007-06-05T22:07:03.000Z",
         "updated":"2010-01-07T13:26:50.000Z",
         "uploader":"GoogleDeveloperDay",
         "category":"News",
         "title":"Google Developers Day US - Maps API Introduction",
         "description":"Google Maps API Introduction ...",
         "tags":[
            "GDD07","GDD07US","Maps"
         ],
         "thumbnail":{
            "default":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/hYB0mn5zh2c/default.jpg",
            "hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/hYB0mn5zh2c/hqdefault.jpg"
         },
         "player":{
            "default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?vu003dhYB0mn5zh2c"
         },
         "content":{
            "1":"rtsp://v5.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy.../0/0/0/video.3gp",
            "5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/hYB0mn5zh2c?f...",
            "6":"rtsp://v1.cache1.c.youtube.com/CiILENy.../0/0/0/video.3gp"
         },
         "duration":2840,
         "aspectRatio":"widescreen",
         "rating":4.63,
         "ratingCount":68,
         "viewCount":220101,
         "favoriteCount":201,
         "commentCount":22,
         "status":{
            "value":"restricted",
            "reason":"limitedSyndication"
         },
         "accessControl":{
            "syndicate":"allowed",
            "commentVote":"allowed",
            "rate":"allowed",
            "list":"allowed",
            "comment":"allowed",
            "embed":"allowed",
            "videoRespond":"moderated"
         }
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Postgres documentation is full of examples for cases you describe https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html. Can't that  be enough or what is unclear from docs?

Answer (score 0):

just use one arrow

```
# select blob->'data'->'items'->0->'title' from so_test;
                  ?column?
----------------------------------------------------
"Google Developers Day US - Maps API Introduction"
(1 row)
```

exchange blob with column name

Comment: Just to comment that if you're looking inside deeply nested path then *path* operators `#>` and `#>>` will give better performance like: `SELECT $${ "parent": { "child1": { "child2": [ 1, { "key": "value" }, 3 ]} } }$$::jsonb #> '{ parent, child1, child2, 1, key }';`. If you do deeply nested lookup as in your example then after each operator another json is "read" as new json until final result achieved.